# Mi funcion de tipo booleana no me devuelve el true

Tags: c++, funciones, booleano

No entiendo por que la funcion `BuscarNumero` no me devuelve un verdadero cuando la condicion se cumple. En teoria deberia agarrar, por que la condicion se cumple con normalidad.

Lo raro es, que cuando retorno el valor de BuscarNumero dentro del funcion principal, ahí sí me lo devuelve, pero cómo tendria que hacer para que si me funcione dentro de la funcion de BuscarNumero.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <wchar.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    using namespace std;

     int i;
     int numero[9];
     int snumero;
     char palabra[4];
     bool Encontrado = false;
    bool BuscarNumero(int numero[]) 
    {
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "NUMEROS GUARDADOS: " << i << endl;
            cout << "Ingrese 9 numero para guardar " << endl;
            cin >> numero[i];
        }
        system("cls");
        cout << "-OK, ya tenemos un array de 9 valores creado.-" << endl;
        cout << "Verifique si un valor que desee se encuentra dentro del array: ";
        cin >> snumero;
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            if(numero[i]==snumero)
            {
                Encontrado = true;
            }
        }
    return Encontrado;
    }
    int main()
    {
        BuscarNumero(numero);
    }**
```

Comment: El código funciona. Podrías replantear tu pregunta? no queda claro el problema: `como tendria que hacer para que si me funcione dentro de la funcion de BuscarNumero`. Eso es muy diferente al título de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en realidad no tiene error tu código, pero recuerda que esa función retorna un valor, pero no lo muestra el return es un retorno de la función esta debes guardarla dentro de una variable y luego mostrarla, tal vez modificando tu main deberías ver el resultado.

```
int main()
    {
        bool valor = BuscarNumero(numero);
        cout << boolalpha << valor << endl;
    }
```

almaceno el resultado de la función en una variable, luego la muestro, utilizo el helper boolalpha para mostrar el booleano en texto.

Comment: Muchas gracias Felipe